# Can't enter directory despite correct permissions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

I have a directory (Owned by `nobody` due to it being a part of a Docker bind mount, combined with user namespace remapping.) that I need to enter. This is its relevant `ls -la` output:

```
drwxrwxr-x    2 nobody   nobody        4096 May 26 14:42 Directory
```

Running as `root`, although I don't belong in either the owner or group of the directory, the directory is world readable and executable, so I should be able to enter it. However, when running `cd Directory`, it fails:

```
bash: cd: Directory: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you created your question and answer after you solved your problem.

Please note that the GNU `ls` long listing `-l` will show you if an alternate access method such as an access control list applies to a file, by appending a character to the file mode bit listing.

And rather than:

```
drwxrwxr-x    2 nobody   nobody        4096 May 26 14:42 Directory
```

your original directory listing probably showed:

```
drwxrwxr-x+   2 nobody   nobody        4096 May 26 14:42 Directory
          ^
           \  Note the extra + character here.
```

Easy to overlook if you're not aware of that convention, but from [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/What-information-is-listed.html#What-information-is-listed)

> When the character following the file mode
>        bits is a space, there is no alternate access method.  When it is a
>        printing character, then there is such a method.
>
> GNU 'ls' uses a '`.`' character to indicate a file with an SELinux
>        security context, but no other alternate access method.
>
> A file with any other combination of alternate access methods is
>        marked with a '`+`' character.

Comment: Ah I see. I recall directly pasting the results in my question, but upon doing a quick test, that is the case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this was caused by a lingering [access control list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access-control_list). The solution to my problem was to remove all access control lists from the directory, and its subdirectories:

```sh
# setfacl -bnR Directory/
```